# Restrict user from opening devtool in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension(which opens up in a new tab in chrome browser) which uses JSON APIs to fetch certain secured data from the server.  I don't want the logged-in user to check those API's. I want to restrict user from opening the chrome devtool.

Can you please help me out in checking whether anybody is trying to open the chrome devtool?

Comment: Even if it is possible, which I seriously doubt, it would be very poor security to rely on something like this.

Comment: It is (or was) possible to detect whether devtools are open, use google search. Not that it'll help you though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable browser developer tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

You can't nor can you stop someone from looking at your APIs.

[How to disable browser developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools)