# How to pause debugger in chrome using javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, pause

I find script pause debugger in chrome when ctrl shift I or F12.
Thank everybody!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type `debugger;` in your js where you want debugger to pause:

[image: Type debugger Screenshot]

Then load the page while developer tools open.

[image: Paused Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Devtools, you can find a tab called Sources in which press ctrl + P and enter the name of the js file you want to debug. Once you open the file, go to the line where you want to debug. Click on the line number at the point to setup a debug point. You can setup Multiple Debugging points the same way too. When the code is called the debugger will pause at the point specified.

Alternatively, In your js code you can specify `debugger;` which will pause the debugger at the location you want.

Comment: No, i have a website and I want user can't use F12 on my website

Comment: @justcntt It is not possible to completely block users from using F12. Thats how it is.

Comment: this would be a related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools