# Prevent inspect element in text field

Tags: php, codeigniter, inspect-element

Here is my input field disabled code

```
<input type="text" class="empl_date form-control" id="staffid" name="staffid" value="<?php echo $employeeworks[0]['employeeCode'];?>" arsley-maxlength="6" placeholder=" Schedule Date"  disabled />
```

How can i prevent inspect element option in this field?

Comment: i thought you will have to do it for whole page because only one element cant be restricted while accessible whole page

Comment: Why you need to achieve this?

Comment: Using right click any one can remove the disabled option.I want to prevent it

Comment: You can't. It's been sent to the browser, users can inspect it.

Comment: Similar question has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools

Comment: _“Using right click any one can remove the disabled option.I want to prevent it”_ - no, what you actually want, is to not use the value that gets send back for anything in the first place. The output is based on a value you have available server-side already - so there is not good reason to take this value from the form data set in the first place, when you are processing the rest of this request.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible.

Code inspectors are designed for debugging HTML and Javascript. They will always do show the live `DOM` object of web page. It means that it reveals the HTML code of everything you see on the page, even if they're generated by Javascript.

Comment: A lot of websites add some scripts to prevent F12 and context menu

Comment: Yes you can disabled those buttons, `ctrl`+`shift`+`I` or  `ctrl`+`shift`+`C` or `F12` or  `ctrl`+`shift`+`J` well there's many more and I think you cannot just disable those buttons.

Comment: @HienNguyen, but you can't disable all approaches

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, it can't be prevented fully, once it is in the browser, user can manipulate it.
Rather than thinking how to prevent the inspect element or dev tools being used on your input, you should think about your goal, what do you want to achieve with this?

If you want to prevent from input value being changed, use some hash generated on server side, that includes value from your `staffid` field and store it in hidden input.

When user submits the form, just regenerate hash using `staffid` value and hash value from input. If they don't match, user has manipulated the `staffid` input manually.

Example:

```
<input type="text" class="empl_date form-control" id="staffid" name="staffid" value="<?php echo $employeeworks[0]['employeeCode'];?>" arsley-maxlength="6" placeholder=" Schedule Date"  disabled />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo md5($employeeworks[0]['employeeCode'] . 'some salt to avoid user just generating hash with md5 using value only'); ?> />
```

and then on submission:

```
$staffid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'staffid');
$hash_input = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'hash');

$hash_check = md5($staffid . 'some salt to avoid user just generating hash with md5 using value only');
if($hash_input !== $hash_check){
//looks like the user manipulated staffid value, throw a validation error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent inspect by right click.

This way to prevent right click

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If user press F12 and click arrow button and inspect, it still ok.
You also can prevent F12 by this code

```
 document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      if(event.keyCode == 123) { //F12 keycode is 123
         return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: And what about other shortcuts to dev tools? Or through browser's menu? It can't be prevented 100%. Developer can't lean on this as a security measure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can not restrict user to check inspect element of any specific element but you can disable completely. Check below code which will not allow user to open debugger and not even page source.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 123) {
      e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
}
```

But this code also has some missings as well. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<input type="text" oncontextmenu="return false;" class="empl_date form-control" id="staffid" name="staffid" value="<?php echo $employeeworks[0]['employeeCode'];?>" arsley-maxlength="6" placeholder=" Schedule Date"  disabled />
```