# How to prevent user for manipulate / change value of variable in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, browser, data-manipulation

Someone change variable value of their data in my website.
Next step this variable value pass to server from api call.

It change value in chrome browser by following steps.
Open chrome -> Inspect Element -> Source -> Scope

I was put all validation like, user can not open inspect element from using of any shortcut keys.

Following is sample code and my situation
[image]

> How can prevent user for modify value of variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704413/prevent-inspect-element-in-text-field. Why not if we disable the user for inspecting the html document by any of the means like by direct opening or shortcut key.

Comment: currently i use javascript-obfuscator. using of this prevent user for debugging https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator

Answer (score 1):

You've should use `const` keyword. It similar to `let` keyword but not the same.

By declaring with `const` keyword it's value can only be **Read** by user and cannot be **modified**. It does not allow to change it's value to change through reassignment and it cannot be redeclared.

If you declare data types with `const` keyword object and arrays, it's properties or items can be **updated** or **removed**.

if you try to reassign the constant variable it will throw an error.

```js
let num1 = 1;
const num2 = 1;

console.log(num1);
num1 = 2;
console.log(num1);

console.log(num2);
num2 = 2;
console.log(num2);
```

Comment: It's not working for me.
Form Inspect Element value was changes

Comment: If you want to secure your code, you just can't do that. But as an alternative you can print a bold message in console or body which display - _warning to user_ . But using `const` keyword has certain protections