# how to disable the edit option in Source tab in the developer tools?

Tags: node.js, angular, developer-tools

I have pushed my code to SIT. Now while testing there is vulnerability from client side that they are able to login with wrong credentials by changing the validation in the Developer tools - Source/webpack. Anybody please help me in disabling the edit option so that they will not able to change the code and functionality. 
I have my code in node JS  and Angular typescript.

Comment: you should do the checking on the server side, not at the client script, nor worry about the developers tools that cause the trouble, check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559427/1874308

Comment: There's nothing you can do m8