# How do you scrape a site that has disabled DevTools

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, cheerio

How do one scrape a site that has disabled Chrome DevTools?

Using Puppeteer, I have tried to get the departure and arrival time for a particular airline using their respective CSS selector, but have not been successful as the DevTool is disabled.

On a little inspection, similar to what Facebook did, I found out that DevTools, the protocol on which Puppeteer controls the browser is disabled by the website. I can't seem to run any valid JavaScript function in the console.

Please, are there any approach to scraping websites like this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the site loads this JavaScript function below which limits my ability to run any valid JavaScript code in the console.

```js
function preventAction(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
  return false
}
jQuery(function() {
  $(document).on("paste", "input", preventAction);
  $(document).on("drop", "input", preventAction);
  $("html").css({
    userSelect: "none"
  })
});
$(function() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    if (!c) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.warn("%cYou are not allowed to use developer tools in Production mode!", "font: 2em sans-serif; color: yellow; background-color: red;")
      }, 1);
      c = 1
    }
    throw "Console is disabled!"
  }
  var a, d = {
    set: function(e) {
      a = e
    },
    get: function() {
      b();
      return a
    }
  };
  console.log("2016 Hitit Computer Services");
  console.warn("%cYou are not allowed to use developer tools in Production mode!", "font: 2em sans-serif; color: #fefefe; background-color: #B5121B; padding: 4px;");
  Object.defineProperty(console, "_commandLineAPI", d);
  Object.defineProperty(console, "__commandLineAPI", d);
  Object.defineProperty(window, "_commandLineAPI", d);
  Object.defineProperty(window, "__commandLineAPI", d);
  Object.defineProperty(window, "console", d)
});
```

Is there anyway to override the function `Object.defineProperty(console,"_commandLineAPI",d)` loaded by the site using Puppeteer so I can traverse through the DOM tree using cheerio?

Comment: Afaik, there's no such thing as `disabling the developer tools`. It's a feature of the browser. It seems that this is only a console output with some styling.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools

Comment: Sites can't disable neither devtools nor the protocol. Your code must be breaking because of something in the site but we can't help without seeing it.

Comment: Disabled DevTools, noice! If you block the request to prodRestrictions.min.js you'll find it working again. I wonder what other magic it contains besides the console message.