# How to avoid modifying the HTML code, from the inspect tool?

Tags: html, jquery, css, youtube, youtube-api

I am inserting a YouTube video, the objective is that the recommended videos will not be seen when pausing or ending the video, I know that this is no longer possible from YouTube, which makes a modification with CSS, and JS, place an image on top of the video when pausing or ending. The objective was fulfilled.

But I was noticing that if the code is inspected with the tool that the browser brings, it is possible that the file containing the CSS and JSS code will be modified from there, and when removing said code that I established, the video is shown without the modification that I did.

I have no idea how to solve this or what I can do, any suggestions I would greatly appreciate.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon/favicon.ico">
    <style>
    .hytPlayerWrap {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ytp-copylink-title{
        display: none;
    }
    .hytPlayerWrap.ended::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 64px 64px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEwIDUxMCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI1NSAxMDJWMEwxMjcuNSAxMjcuNSAyNTUgMjU1VjE1M2M4NC4xNSAwIDE1MyA2OC44NSAxNTMgMTUzcy02OC44NSAxNTMtMTUzIDE1My0xNTMtNjguODUtMTUzLTE1M0g1MWMwIDExMi4yIDkxLjggMjA0IDIwNCAyMDRzMjA0LTkxLjggMjA0LTIwNC05MS44LTIwNC0yMDQtMjA0eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
    }
    .hytPlayerWrap.paused::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 640px;
        height: 340px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 40px 40px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEiIHdpZHRoPSIxNzA2LjY2NyIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNzA2LjY2NyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEyODAgMTI4MCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE1Ny42MzUgMi45ODRMMTI2MC45NzkgNjQwIDE1Ny42MzUgMTI3Ny4wMTZ6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIi8+PC9zdmc+);
    }
.hytPlayerWrap.ended iframe,
.hytPlayerWrap.paused iframe{
visibility: hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

    .hytPlayerWrap {
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
</style>
    <title> 2021</title>
</head>
<body id="plenario">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-12">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                <div class="hytPlayerWrapOuter" >
                    <div class="hytPlayerWrap" style="background-image:url(imgs/Captura.jpg)">
                        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/wzWmZYi4qMg?rel=0&controls=0&enablejsapi=1"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-2">&nbsp;</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seccion-regresar-plenario"> 
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/utiles.js"></script>

<script>

    "use strict";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        if (window.hideYTActivated) return;
        let onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks = [];
        for (let playerWrap of document.querySelectorAll(".hytPlayerWrap")) {
            let playerFrame = playerWrap.querySelector("iframe");
            let tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            let onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    playerWrap.classList.add("ended");
                } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                    playerWrap.classList.add("paused");
                } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    playerWrap.classList.remove("ended");
                    playerWrap.classList.remove("paused");
                }
            };
            let player;
            onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks.push(function () {
                player = new YT.Player(playerFrame, {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});
            });
            playerWrap.addEventListener("click", function () {
                let playerState = player.getPlayerState();
                if (playerState == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    player.seekTo(0);
                } else if (playerState == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                    player.playVideo();
                }
            });
        }
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
            for (let callback of onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        window.hideYTActivated = true;
    });
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but i doubt you can get around that.

Comment: Thanks for comment. In the same way I am looking for some other alternative.

Comment: Do you think it would be feasible to disable the keys, right click, so that the inspect code is not shown?

Comment: You can't stop the user using their local inspect tools AFAK. There's lots of discussion around this topic. For example [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict user from editing code through inspect element.

But it does not risk your official website and only change code on there side.

Comment: The goal I want to achieve is that it is not shared, it is not seen in the youtube video share link. I know I can upload the video to the server, but the project I do will have many users watching the video, then it will not support the server, for that reason I manage it on YouTube.