# Can an application prevent snooping through devtools console

Tags: reactjs, security, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possilbe for a React application to prevent snooping of request and responses through devtools console. We check to see if the DevTools console is open but if its docked on a separate window we are not able to find out if its open. How to prevent this information from showing up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable browser developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools)

Comment: And if you think this would give you [tag:security] you're dead wrong.